# Толстые пунктирные линии в OpenGL

Tags: opengl, графика, шейдеры

Я использую триангуляцию для рисования толстых линий. Каждый сегмент превращается в прямоугольник, состоящий из двух треугольников.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, для того чтобы добавить пунктир, я создаю текстуру из одного альфа канала, которая описывает паттерн.  Чтобы паттерн не начинался заново на каждом сегменте, я рассчитываю параметр lineSoFar (длина линии от начала), который выступает по сути в качества текстурной координаты. Во фрагментном шейдере использую значение альфа-канала чтобы определить где штрих а где пропуск.

```
float a  = texture2D(u_tex, v_normal/u_tex_len).a;
gl_FragColor = u_color*a;
```

Но это работает только если при триангуляции не рассчитывать митер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении же митера, паттерн растягивается. Что логично, ведь длина внешнего края отличается о длины внутреннего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться такого результата?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое митер?

Comment: @user7860670 Способ соединения линий. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/painting/linejoin.png

Comment: триангуляцию митера обычно делают отдельно от основных сегментов линии, и все становится еще сложнее если используется полупрозрачность